# ACR122U SDK for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, nfc, acr122

I just got a NFC Reader (ACS ACR122U), but the SDK available is for Windows only.

Where can I find a SDK for Mac OSX? I already contacted helpdesk of the hardware provider but until now I don't get any response from them.

Comment: @michael-roland thanks for adding the tag, i have no privileges yet for adding new tags..

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Want to play with this but can't see to find any information.

Answer (score 3):

libnfc works with the ACR122U, according to http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=ACR122 .

To install libnfc on OSX, see: http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc#Mac_OS_X

Answer (score 0):

To add privileges you run `vigr` and `vigr -s` on OSX.
On linux you can do the same or use

```
usermod <user> -G <group>
```

Where group is `libnfc` or `nfc` or something like that.

Comment: sorry, I dont know if i was right. cannot find vigr anymore, vipw is working anyhow.